# NSString is nil after popViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to set a variable in the UIViewController I have, but after I return to the controller in viewWillAppear it print null.

the float need to be : A calls B -> B set the string in A and return to A -> A print the string.

UIViewController A:

```
@property NSString *paramsAsString;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      NSLog(@"STRING: %@", _paramsAsString); } // output 'STRING: (null)'

- (void)goToBrokersSearch {
   B *destController = [[B alloc] initWithSearchParams: A.paramsAsString];
   destController.delegate = view; // view is a non nil A UIViewController object
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:destController animated:NO];}
```

UIViewController B:

```
@property A *delegate;

- (void)search {
   _delegate.paramsAsString = params; //  params - non nil NSString 
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:false];}
```

Comment: `destController.delegate = view;` Did you meant `self` instead if `view`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the order of calling for these functions. I would suggest you use breakpoint and debug if the order of function calls is as you expecting. and the second doubt:  paramsAsString should not be weak property or variable.